# The Events Calendar and Easy Digital Downloads adding customer notes to Attendee export

Tags: plugins

I am using The Events Calendar Pro, Tickets Plus and Easy Digital Downloads for a client's event site. Unfortunately they don't have an easy option to add a note to an attendee on the backend and have it export.

I was able to add an extra column to the attendee section that (I've tested) does export.

EDD has a customer notes section and I was hoping I could pull those notes into the extra column I just made in the attendee area of an event.

Here's what I have so far in my child theme's functions.php file:

```
# Register our extra column
add_filter( 'tribe_tickets_attendee_table_columns', function( $columns ) {
    $columns['extra'] = 'My extra column';
    return $columns;
} );
# Populate the extra column ($item can be used to identify the actual attendee object)
add_filter( 'tribe_events_tickets_attendees_table_column', function( $val, $item, $column ) {
    static $count = 0;
    if ( 'extra' === $column ) {
        $val = 'Extra column value ' . ++$count;
    }
    return $val;
}, 10, 3 );
```

but I cannot figure out how to get that info specific to the customer. I was able to get ALL of the notes showing (from every customer) into that column, but that was not what I wanted... It needs to only show the notes specific to that customer. I hope that makes sense. 
Any help would be much appreciated!